# SSRS report view blur when scrolling

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

SSRS report is not rendering properly (blurs) while scrolling down through the report. I am using IE11 and SSRS2012.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Reporting Services issue. Have you tried a different browser? Alternatively, try changing the document compatibility setting of IE11. Is it possible for you to take a screenshot of the blurring and post it here?

Comment: [link](http://s879.photobucket.com/user/Padmarajr/media/error_zpse10aa4fa.jpg.html) to error snap.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved.Issue was due to browser compatibility view which was set to IE5.
I changed SSRS report viewer file located at
Microsoft SQL Server\MSRSXX.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\Report.aspx

added meta tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

to force browser to render in latest version available.

Taken [Help](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/519aa473-5093-4545-9d3b-e301aeece07c/issue-with-ssrs-data-bar-in-ie-9ie-10?forum=sqlreportingservices) from.